# Как сделать запрос в базу данных так, чтоб одно из полей в ответе было константой. Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Есть таблица в бд, из нее нужно выбрать телефоны по некоторым условиям, и добавить к выборке поле с константой, например 1. Грубо говоря нужен вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT phone, 2 AS user_group FROM `users` WHERE ...
```

Вот код где пытаюсь сделать этот запрос

```
Users::find()
        ->select([
            'phone',
            'user_group' => 2,
        ])
        ->where(...)
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
```

В результате приложение оборачивает двойку в кавычки, и бд пытается найти столбец под названием `2`. Вот ошибка.

[image: Ошибка]

Оборачивал двойку в разные кавычки, пробовал писать `2 AS user_group` вместо `'user_group' => 2` результат похожий.

Comment: Что-то типа `'user_group' => new  \yii\db\Expression("'2'")])`...

Comment: Да точно! Спасибо!